# Why is it false that anything wrapped inside Mutex is thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, rust, thread-safety, mutex

It seems to me that if a data structure requires a lock for its contents to be accessed, then it doesn't matter what sort of data structure is inside.  Even if the stuff on the inside is not thread safe (neither `Send` nor `Sync`), there will never be a situation where data races occur since only one thread will be allowed to work on it at a given time.

Yet, [in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Send-for-Mutex%3CT%3E), `Mutex` is `Send` or `Sync` only if the interior is correspondingly `Send` or `Sync`.

Is there a case where we lose memory safety despite requiring a lock?

Comment: When you wrap an existing object `x` inside a mutex, it is not possible for the language to guarantee that 1) you haven't kept a reference to `x` that could be accessed with holding the lock, or 2) you don't have an operation that can return `x` *or a component of `x`* without wrapping it in the same mutex. If either of those things can happen, there is a thread-safety issue.  (P.S.  I'm not a Rust programmer.  This is "from first principles".  It will be *why* ...)

Comment: This explains it; I didn't occur to me you could do thread-unsafe things before creating the Mutex and passing it off to another thread.  Would you kindly convert this comment to an answer?  I'll give folks an opportunity to answer, but it's likely I'll accept yours.

Comment: @StephenC This may just be unfortunate wording, but Rust *will* prevent *references* from existing outside of the mutex while its locked. If you meant some other pointer-like thing (that doesn't use Rust's lifetimes), then that is still true.

Comment: There may be other answers here: [Why does Arc<Mutex<T>> require T: Sync + Send?](/q/64779742/2189130)

Comment: @kmdreko - You are correct.  I am using incorrect terminology.  But it looks like my explanation is incorrect anyway.  (Though that would be the explanation in many other languages.  For example, in Java the scenarios I am talking about could be characterized as a consequence of "leaky" abstractions.)

Comment: Note that `Mutex` never requires its interior to be `Sync` (which would be redundant anyway since the whole point of `Mutex` is to _make_ it `Sync`), it only requires `Send`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the reason why a type may not be `Send`, and then consider if `Mutex` remedies that reason.

The type `Rc` is `!Send` because it holds a shared resource that is not managed atomically. Thus it could cause a data race if two handles to the same resource were used on separate threads simultaneously. Even if one or both were wrapped in mutexes, that doesn't address the thread-safety of the type.

Another case (though weird in this situation) is a `MutexGuard` itself is `!Send` because it relies on system facilities that requires the unlock to happen on the same thread as the lock was acquired ([source](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/23465)). If a `Mutex` was `Send` regardless of its contents, then you could use it to smuggle the guard to another thread and violate those invariants (and cause UB as far as the source above reports).

So a `Mutex` providing exclusivity does not automatically protect the type from other reasons why thread-locality is a concern.

Comment: An other one (though it could be argued as a superset of the mutex one) is thread-local dependency, it could not be send because the target thead may not have the thread-local store initialised at all, let alone be a complete copy of the source. That shows up once in a while e.g. a long time ago sqlite connections made use of TLS, so you could not use them from any thread other than their creator.